# In cluster analysis, can you use Gower's coefficient of similarity with a k-means clustering method?

Tags: clustering, k-means, mixed-type-data, gower-similarity

I am researching cluster analysis, and I am interested in variables that are both categorical and continuous, for which I have read that a Gower's similarity coefficient is a good proximity measure. I have read that Gower's similarity coefficient is generally not compatible with Ward's method, so I was planning to initially cluster using average linkage, but I was also seeking to compare the cluster structure (for content validity purposes) with another clustering method, specifically the k-means method, using the number of clusters and initial centers obtained in the average linkage method. Is Gower's coefficient of similarity a compatible proximity measure for k-means method?

Comment: `Gower's similarity coefficient is generally not compatible with Ward's method` You might have also read that it is not comatible with k-means as well. Because k-means and Ward are relatives. Won't you prefer k-medoids in place of k-means?

Comment: Thank you-- that's exactly what I needed to know. It looks like k-medoids would be more appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

K-means is really *only* sensible for squared euclidean distance.

The objective function of the two steps must agree for the algorithm to always converge.

**Recomputing the mean optimizes the sum-of-squares assignment** (the mean is the least squares estimator!). Therefore, the distance function *must* optimize the same objective, unless you also compute the mean differently.

And last but not least, when you are using Gower that somewhat implies that you have categorical attributes. *How would you compute a mean/centroid there, in the first place?*